# why the event of asp:button does not fire although all inputs are valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, submit

I have an aspx page with some asp:textBox.

every TextBox has some validator controls.
I use bootstrap glyphicons for notifying the user about the validation of the input.

for example:
aspx:

```
<div id="trId" runat="server" class="row">
<div class="col col-md-1 col-xs-1">
</div>
<div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-3>your id</div>
<div class="col col-md-5  col-xs-6">
    <div id="divId" class="form-group has-feedback">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="9" TabIndex="4" EnableViewState="false" ValidationGroup="idValidation" onchange="validateWithFeedback('idValidation','txtId');" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback "></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorId" CssClass="validation" Visible="false" ControlToValidate="txtId" ValidationGroup="idValidation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" CssClass="validation" ControlToValidate="txtId" ValidationGroup="idValidation" runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="\d{1,9}" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" CssClass="validation" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtId" ValidationGroup="idValidation" ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateID" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function validateWithFeedback(group,id) {
    if (Page_ClientValidate(group)) {
        $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').addClass('has-success');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    }
    else {
        $("#" + id).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-success');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        Page_IsValid = false;
    }
    var required = false;
    var validators = $(Page_Validators);
    if ($("#" + id).val() == "" && $("#" + id).text() == "") {
       // debugger;
        for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate==id && $(Page_Validators[i]).attr('data-val-evaluationfunction') == "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid")
                required = true;
        }
        if (!required) {
            $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-success');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        }
    }
}
```

submit button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn-sm btn-info" Text='submit' TabIndex="19" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></asp:Button>
```

javascript:

```
function validateWithFeedback(group,id) {
    if (Page_ClientValidate(group)) {
        $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').addClass('has-success');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    }
    else {
        $("#" + id).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-success');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        Page_IsValid = false;
    }
    var required = false;
    var validators = $(Page_Validators);
    if ($("#" + id).val() == "" && $("#" + id).text() == "") {
       // debugger;
        for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate==id && $(Page_Validators[i]).attr('data-val-evaluationfunction') == "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid")
                required = true;
        }
        if (!required) {
            $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').removeClass('has-success');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
            $("#" + id).parent('div').children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        }
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
function Validate() { 

    validateWithFeedback('idValidation', 'txtId');

    var isValid = true;

    isValid = isValid && Page_ClientValidate('idValidation');

    return isValid;
}
```

everything is perfect, except of fact that when I click on btnSubmit the event in server side doesn't fire although all inputs are valid.
what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure of the `ClientValidationFunction="ValidateID"`. It seems as if there is no function like `ValidateID`. Though there is one `Validate` function. Shouldn't that be in place of `ValidateID`?

Comment: oh no, I have both functions ValidateId and Validate.